Are there any standards for storing checksums of a repository?
I have a repository with many files (mostly binary, images and raw data) and some documentation. The files are stored in a hierarchical folder structure; I want to allow checking the fixity of the file for detecting data corruption. I am currently generating a .json file representing the structure and containing its checksum for each file. I also included some metadata containing, for instance, the date and the algorithm I used to calculate the checksum.
Once the folder structure is generated, I transfer the data to different storage solutions (cloud, HHD, SSD, etc.) I then use a custom Python script to check the fixity (i.e. calculating the checksum).
I was wondering if there are any standards for storing checksum, i.e. a file format that can be accepted by specific software devoted to this task and not only by my custom script?

There are many such schemes, but the most advanced ones tend to turn into full-blown file systems with error correction - such as ZFS or btrfs. Depending on your circumstances, it might me much easier for you simply to switch to one of those.

What's the total data size of these files and how often do they change? In many cases, a VCS may be by far the simplest answer here.

Thanks @KilianFoth! Unfortunatly I need some more flexible solution, because I have to transfer data in HD, and Clouds and I would like to just be able to check the fixity, in a standardize manner

Most of the data is binary, except for some texts.  Once the data are created I just need to transfer to different storages.

Git also checksums the entire file tree to allow for integrity checks, but if you're working with large binary files it may be less well suited. But it does sound like you want something Git-like, just without commit history.

@amon yes, for binary data it's not the best

Why the downvotes? I think the question is quite clear and focus on a specific issues.

@GM because the questions asks for recommendation on a tool/format, which is off-topic because there is no single correct answer. Yes, rules are stupid like that.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

@Basilevs thanks for your answer, many questions don't have a single correct answer, but here there is actually I single correct answer could be there are no current standards, or each developer uses what he wants so feel free to do the same. Or in case there is a standard the name of the standard.

shasum Unix command outputs data in a predefined format, that can later be used for validation.
Generate sums:
shasum --algorithm 512 * > sha512.txt

Check sums:
shasum --algorithm 512 --check sha512.txt
1.txt: FAILED
Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 14.48.08.png: OK
Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 14.48.18.png: OK
Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 16.25.24.png: OK
Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 16.26.21.png: OK

For the reference, the file format is:
98514de29450e22e0d918546b797b20c7a2ba33b  1.txt
5c24c38252f26b91948a25e08189a0d224780be8  Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 14.48.08.png
29172bda2ba9661e0b2b32536544576892f8abd1  Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 14.48.18.png
5d85859d2da0a08ee0643770b6d23bc51f9236cb  Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 16.25.24.png
39602e699b7d2a05b12f79aa637f1c78326472f1  Screenshot 2024-07-22 at 16.26.21.png


Thanks a lot Basilievs, your solutions get closer to what I want because that's defenely a common format. I was wondering if the format is somehow defined.

For these kinds of things, asking for standards often isn't helpful.
You need a solution that works for your case (as can be inferred from the comments, you seem to be unhappy with the "standard" solutions offered).
A simple solution that's working well enough for me is to compute some checksum (MD5, SHA, really doesn't matter if you're not into critical security) for each file.
With a standard GNU/Linux environment (or something reasonably compatible, such as WSL) you can create such a list using this:
shasum $(find . -type f | sort)

Checking whether the current sums are equal to the last saved list is a simple matter of shasum -c (thank @Basilevs) or diff if you need to see whether new files appeared, as the -c option only checks the listed files.
Apparently you have already implemented a similar scheme, so it may be best to just stay with that.

Is not validation built into the shasum?

@Basilevs You're right! Never occurred to me to look for that...

thanks for your answer, these answers were helpful. I have now identified that the common format is simply  . Using this standard instead of using my JSON file would have allowed other software engineers to test the fixity using a common tool like shasum.
